# How to store a set/array of unique numbers in a MySQL cell

Tags: mysql

I am trying to store an array/set of unique elements in a MySQL cell.It would be something like following:

```
user_id     liked_friends_id
  1            [3,6,4]
  2            [1,2,4]
```

Here the **liked_friends_id** is an array/set which stores all unique ids.

Is there any way to implement it?
How can I implement pushing to the array/set while enforcing unique array elements.

Answer (score 2):

*Don't* store CSV data in your MySQL table.  Unlike a database like Postgres, MySQL does not have an array type.  Instead, store each user-friend relationship in a single record:

```
user_id     liked_friends_id
1           3
1           6
1           4
2           1
2           2
2           4
```

Proceeding this way leaves your database relatively *normalized*.  If you want to ensure that you do not store duplicate user-friend relationships, then add a unique constraint on these two columns:

```
ALTER TABLE friends ADD UNIQUE unq_idx (user_id, liked_friends_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could re-think your schema to check if you really want to store `liked_friends_id` in the same table. You could split it into another table with each `liked friends id` as a foreign constraint to the primary key `user_id`. That way, you can enforce uniqueness via MySQL itself.

Another way of doing it would be to serialize the array and storing it as `varchar` if you're using PHP/Java/.. for handling the queries. In that case, you will have to enforce uniqueness via the programming language.